# Vehicle Miles Traveled in New Jersey before 1981

Tags: data-request, government, transportation, state

I am looking for public road mileage or total vehicle miles traveled in the state of New Jersey for any of the years before 1981. Any help would be much appreciated.

VMT for 1981 and beyond are [here](http://www.state.nj.us/transportation/refdata/roadway/vmt.shtm). I've tried contacting the number listed on this page to no avail.

Comment: If you're in (or near) New Jersey, you can contact the New Jersey DOT for access to their library : http://www.state.nj.us/transportation/refdata/library/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

National statistics for miles traveled on different roads and for different uses have been compiled for the United States by the Department of Transportation.

- Historical listings [from 1936-1995](http://www.fhwa.dot.gov/ohim/summary95/vm201.pdf)
- Detailed listings from [1995-present](http://www.fhwa.dot.gov/policyinformation/quickfinddata/qftravel.cfm)
- National Household Travel Survey (online [data extraction tool and tables](http://nhts.ornl.gov/tools.shtml))
- Specific to New Jersey ([after 1995](http://www.rita.dot.gov/bts/sites/rita.dot.gov.bts/files/publications/state_transportation_statistics/new_jersey/index.html))

Even at the New Jersey state level, the [statistics](http://www.state.nj.us/transportation/refdata/) only go back to 1995, but they are complete for [miles traveled](http://www.state.nj.us/transportation/refdata/roadway/vmt.shtm).